# How to run a Python click module multiple times based on input prameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-click, command-line-tool

Consider you have a function `run()` decorated as click.command() and multiple click.options() for default values and more specifications. In this `run` function I want to call my other 'sub' functions of the tool one by one with the given parameters.

```
@click.command("run")
@click.options(_some_options)
def run(ctx, par1: str, par2: str, par3: int):
    ctx.invoke(some_other_func, par1=par1, par2=par2, par3=par3)
```

This is running and works well so far. But now I'd like to open up the possibility to insert multiple values for the second parameter (par2) as a list of strings and execute the run function for each of the given strings in the list. Imagine an input like:

```
run(par1 = "hello", par2 = ["man", "woman", "child"], par3 = 3)
```

Expected Output:

```
"hello man 3"
"hello woman 3"
"hello child 3"
```

I tried using a decorator like:

```
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def run_wrapper(ctx, par1:str, par2:list, par3:int)
        run_unwrapped = run.__wrapped__
        for var in par2:
            run_unwrapped(ctx, par1, par2, par3)
    return run_wrapper
```

and this worked outside of the context of `click` but with click it doesn't. I read that one should use
the `@click.pass_context` [click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#decorating-commands](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#decorating-commands) instead but I have difficulties with this. Especially accessing the given parameters and the multiple calls of "run" just do not work.. Another difficulty is the input of a arbitrary long list - couldn't find a solution for this as well (multiple=True in the slick.options() does not work as I expected..).

Is a wrapper for this task actually a good idea? I thought of using this as I do not want to change my whole code and clutter it with for-loops.. but if there is a better idea I'd be grateful for it!

I'm a beginner with Python and Stack overflow - please be kind :)

Comment: can't you use `for`-loop directly in `def run()` ? Eventually you can check `isinstance(par2, string)` and convert `par2="string"` to list `par2 = [par2]` and run with for-loop even if you us esingle string. Eventually you could send values as single string `"man,woman,child"` and use `split(",")` in `run()` - it will produce list of strings even if you use `"man".split(",")`

Comment: that would probably work but I'd like to wrap a decorator around the subfunctions at one point as well since some of them are downloads, it might come in usefull to cluster them as well. I was looking for a better and less clunky way to to this than for-loops in each and every command function.. also, the other variables may also change to lists later on and then it will get really clunky with directly integrated for-loops

Comment: I don't understand why you use `run.__wrapper__` instead of `func`

Comment: good question, I tried it out with `func` and it doesn't make a difference.. ended up changing my workflow as I didn't find a solution to this.. Thanks anyway! Have a good day.